# How to use custom properties in a ControlTemplate trigger

Tags: wpf

I have a class derived from slider which uses a custom control template and has a few added dependency properties.  I would like to fire triggers within the template based on the new properties.

For example, I have a new dependency property called ThumbIsVisible which when set to false I want just the thumb portion of my slider to be hiddin.  My control template looks like:

```
<Slider.Template>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
...
<Track.Thumb>
<Thumb x:Name="m_Thumb" Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
...
```

I would like to add in a trigger that looks like:

```
<ControlTempate.Trigger>
<Trigger Property="ThumbIsVisible" Value="False">
<Setter TargetName="m_Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
```

Right off the bat I can see this won't work as I have the control tempate's target type set to Slider.  However, if I change that to say:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:myCustomSlider}">
```

then I run into problems with the template type differing from the controls.  The only way around this is to create the xaml using the local:myCustomSlider as the type instead of Slider. However, doing this causes lots of problems with VisualStudio's designer and code behind.

Does anyone know if there is a standard way to get around all of this?  As a workaround I tried adding to the template's triggers via code-behind but have not been able to get that to work.

Comment: Add the solution as an answer and accept it so that this doesn't sit around as unanswered.

Comment: I will as soon as I get to 100 reputation or my 8 hour newbie self-answer limit is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an even simpler way to solve this problem.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>   
  <Trigger Property=local:CustomSlider.ThumbIsVisible" Value="False">     
    <Setter TargetName="m_Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
  </Trigger> 
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

where local is the namespace of the CustomSlider class.

Comment: `DataTrigger` doesn't contain `Property` property in .NET 4. How is it working for you?

Comment: @Nayan: A bit late, but I guess this is supposed to be `Trigger` not `DataTrigger`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it only takes me 30 minutes after posting my question to find the answer when I spent two days looking for it first.  Oh well, the solution is to use DataTriggers.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ThumbIsVisible}" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="m_Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
  </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The key is to use the RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} to find the custom property.  After that it works exactly as expected.